# Examples of doubling metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

I keep reading a lot of metric space results which are frames for doubling metric spaces.  However, besides some obvious examples (such as Euclidean case, discrete spaces, or quasi-symmetric images of other doubling spaces (so in my mind the first two)) I can't seem to find many examples of doubling metric spaces.

Can anyone recommend a reference where I can find a reasonable length list of examples (or results of the form all __ are *doubling*)?

Comment: You might take a look here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194683/are-carnot-groups-as-carnot-caratheodory-metric-spaces-doubling

Comment: And https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375094/which-groups-are-doubling

Comment: Is there a function $f(n,K)$ such that all Riemannian manifolds of dimension $d$ and curvature $\ge K$ are doubling with doubling constant $f(n,K)$?

Comment: @MattF do you have a reference?

Comment: Actually, my idea doesn’t work: in hyperbolic space with $d=3$ and $k=-1$, a ball of radius $r$ has volume $v(r)=\pi \sinh(2r)-2\pi r$, so $v(2r)/v(r)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Another idea: Does $$d(z,w) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{z-n}-\frac{1}{w-n} \right|$$ give a metric on $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z}$, and is it doubling?

Comment: The above function $d$ is well-defined, which we can see by writing it as 
$$d(z,w)=|z-w|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|z-n||w-n|}$$
Letting $r=\max(\text{Re}(z),\text{Re}(w))$, we can bound the terms in the sum with $n>r$ by the convergent sum $$\sum_n 1/(r-n)^2$$
The above function $d$ is also a metric. If we abbreviate
$$d_n(z,w)=\Big|\frac{1}{z-n}-\frac{1}{w-n}\Big|$$ then $d_n$ satisfies the triangle inequality for each $n$, so the sum of the $d_n$ must satisfy the triangle inequality also. I suspect that $d$ is a doubling metric too.

Comment: This is a very interesting one!